How to pass a parameter to @await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(TopMenuViewComponent))?
I'm working with views, not a controller. How to pass a parameter to
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(TopMenuViewComponent)) and then in the component TopMenuViewComponent  (Default.cshtml) get this parameter and check it?
c#, nopCommerce
Previously I passed the parameter correctly like this
@await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductBox", item, new ViewDataDictionary(this.ViewData) {
   {
      "val",
      "HomeGrid"
   }
})

But I don't know how to pass it to a component.

It looks like you're trying to pass data from a view to a ViewComponent.
You can achieve this by using the Component.InvokeAsync method within your .cshtml file.
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(TopMenuViewComponent), new { widgetZone = "your_widgetzone_name", additionalData = Model })

